# How to profile only parts of the code with Blackfire?

Tags: php, blackfire

Reading https://blackfire.io/docs/reference-guide/php-sdk I see that

> The $probe instance can also be used to instrument precisely only part of your code

But

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$blackfire = new \Blackfire\Client();

spl_autoload_call('\SendinBlue\Base32');

$probe = $blackfire->createProbe(null, false);
$probe->enable();
\SendinBlue\Base32::decode(\SendinBlue\Base32::encode('Test'));
$probe->disable();
$blackfire->endProbe($probe);
```

get me [the following graph](https://blackfire.io/profiles/7d4b1083-542d-4d51-bef1-4982ff457eac/graph):

[image]

But I only wanted to benchmark

```
\SendinBlue\Base32::decode(\SendinBlue\Base32::encode('Test'));
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

After talking with someone from the Blackfire team it seems the problem comes from their side. I'll update and accept this answer when I'll know more.